# What is the scope of multiple vars defined on the same line?

Tags: javascript

Simple question. 
Today I was writing something simple like this:

```
var deferred = null;
var user = null;
var campaigns = null;
```

But my editor suggested me to put the definition of these vars on the same line, like this:

`var deferred = user = campaigns = null;`

The scope of the two definitions is the same?

I was wondering if with the same-line-definition make user and campaigns global and not local to the function where them have been defined.

Comment: The scope is still the same, but often much harder to read.

Comment: +1 because I was wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to initalise all of them to `null` by the way? Could you not just do `var deferred, user, campaigns;` and leave them as `undefined`, which they will implicitly be.

Comment: In retrospect, this makes perfect sense; I hadn't thought it through. Interesting, though, and I was still completely wrong, which is nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Warning**... you are not declaring three variables. You are only declaring one (`deferred`). This will mean the others leak to the global scope (or throw a reference error in strict mode).

You need to declare all three variables first:

```
var deferred, user, campaigns;
deferred = user = campaigns = null;
```

To demonstrate it, run this in your console:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var x = y = null; // Throws a reference error
}());
```

In my opinon the cleanest solution is to use a single `var` statement with multiple initialisers (or simply forget the initialisers... do you really need to initialse everything to `null`? They'll be implicitly initialised to `undefined` anyway):

```
var deferred = null,
    campaigns = null,
    user = null;
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: +1; `(function f() {var a = b = c = 123;})(); alert(typeof a + "/" + typeof b);` for "undefined/number"

Comment: @FlashThunder - yes. Try the example in your browser console.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive explanation!

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answers, javascript has what is known as [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), no matter in what part of the function you declare the variable, it will be moved to the begining of the function. For example:

```
function test() { 
    var i;

    i = 5;
    console.log(i);
    // Some more code code 

    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        var k = i + j;
        console.log(k);
    }
}
```

Will be interpreted by the javascript engine as this:

```
function test() { 
    var i;
    var j;
    var k;        

    i = 5;
    console.log(i);
    // Some more code code 

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        k = i + j;
        console.log(j);
    }
}
```

*(As poited by [@Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k), this process is known as [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)).*

There is no such thing as block scope in javascript, and moving your variables to the start of the function is one the [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) recomendations will yell at you.

So, declarations like:

```
var i, j;
```

Or

```
var i;
var j;
```

Or even,

```
var i = 0, j = 3;
```

Use the same scope, function scope.

*For more deep info about some javascript gotchas, consult the Douglas Crockford's javascript material ([videos](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_DKkVvOt6dk&ei=VjLhUtT4OIfKsQTy8oGwDQ&usg=AFQjCNH3t0f_OT84xwwtVifDFUohQEFY5Q&sig2=1lb1b-kLU66rorImWg_pkA&bvm=bv.59568121,d.cWc), [site](http://javascript.crockford.com/), etc)*

Comment: The term for which is *hoisting*.